# implementing Active Record Guide 2.4 The has_many :through Association

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to implement the example in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

But I'm not sure what the proper way is? Do you create migrations first and then apply the has many through in the model by changing the model?

```
hospital$ rails g model Physician name:string
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20140807183053_create_physicians.rb
      create    app/models/physician.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      create      test/models/physician_test.rb
      create      test/fixtures/physicians.yml
hospital$ rails g model Patient name:string
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20140807183112_create_patients.rb
      create    app/models/patient.rb
      invoke    test_unit
hospital$ rails g model Appointment physician:references patient:references appointment_date:datetime
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20140807183152_create_appointments.rb
      create    app/models/appointment.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      create      test/models/appointment_test.rb
      create      test/fixtures/appointments.yml
```

These are the models generated:

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

is there a step by step guide on implementing a has many through model? The guide explains the idea, I understand it but I'm not sure about the correct way to actually implement it or if it even matters? I'm confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the order in which you write the migration or the code of your app doesn't matter. But your code will only work once you **run** the migration with `rake db:migrate`.

In your posted code, you're obviously missing the **has_many** methods. Maybe you like [this quick tip](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/what-is-a-has_many-through-association-in-ruby-on-rails-treehouse-quick-tip) about what is and how to build **has_many through associations**

**Edit:**

You absolutely can manually put the has_many in it. The generator makes it easier though. But if you're confuse, I suggest you to write the code manually and run the migration after.

Comment: So I manually add the has many through in the model? I was just confused because I thought I should it do only thru a migration

Comment: Thanks, I thought everything has to be done thru a migration!!

Comment: How would you do it personally? make migrations for everything?

Comment: I generate the model through a generator. Then I run it. Then I add extra methods in the model, whatever is missing and stuff...